# Edge Detection on 2d Black color rectangle with white Background

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-recognition

I am trying to find the edges of black color rectangle with white background, but I don't know how to find the edges of rectangle.

Code so far is:

```
private void Vicky(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(file.FileName);
    }
}

private void process(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
        {
            Color pixelColor = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);
            if (pixelColor.R == 0 && pixelColor.G == 0 && pixelColor.B == 0)
            {
                for (int x = i; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = x; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                    {
                    }
                }
            } // end if.
        } // end inner for.
    } //end outer for.
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
} //end process.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just go to all 4 directions until you find a pixel that is not white?

```
int left, right, top, bottom;
for (int x = i; x < bmp.Width; x++)
{
    Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
    if (c.R != 0 || c.G != 0 || c.B != 0) {
        right = x;
        break;
    }
}
for (int x = i; x > 0; x--)
{
    Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
    if (c.R != 0 || c.G != 0 || c.B != 0) {
        left = x;
        break;
    }
}
// ... Two more loops for top and bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure edges are 1px wide and straight you could test bmp.GetPixel(i+1, j); and bmp.GetPixel(i, j+1); for blackness. That would mean you have top left corner. Then simply continue on both sides to determine width and height.

btw, you had 2 extra } in your code. Considering one was for closing the class, the other one was probably causing your code not to compile.